# Pandas DataFrame - assign 1,0 values based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, calculated-columns

I've got a dataframe containing country names & their percentage of energy output. 
I need to add a new column that assigns a 1 or 0, based on whether the country's energy output is above or below the median of energy output. Some dummy code is:

```
import pandas as pd
def answer():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['china', 'america', 'canada'], 'output': [33.2, 15.0, 5.0]})
    df['newcol'] = df.where(df['output'] > df['output'].median(), 1, 0)
    return df['newcol']
answer()
```

the code returns

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

I feel like this is an incredibly simple fix but I'm new to working with `Pandas`.
Please help end my frustration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Vaishali explains why `pd.DataFrame.where` didn't work as you expected and suggested you use `np.where` instead, which is very good advice.

I'll offer up that you could have simply converted your boolean result to integers.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['china', 'america', 'canada'],
    'output': [33.2, 15.0, 5.0]
})
```

**Option 1**

```
df['newcol'] = (df['output'] > df['output'].median()).astype(int)
```

---

**Option 2**
Or faster yet by using the underlying numpy arrays

```
o = df['output'].values
df['newcol'] = (o > np.median(o)).astype(int)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I had tried boolean masking but was struggling to re-format the returned True|False values. I'm very much new to Pandas and i'm finding it a struggle to learn all the documentation. you and @Vaishali have been very informative :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need loop as the solution is vectorized.

```
df['newcol'] = np.where((df['output'] > df['output'].median()), 1, 0)

    name    output  newcol
0   china   33.2    1
1   america 15.0    0
2   canada  5.0     0
```

For the error wrong number of items passed, df.where works a little different from np.where. It Returns an object of same shape as self whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other. So its returning a dataframe in your case with two columns instead of a series and hence when you try to assign that dataframe to a series, you get the error message.

Comment: I've been wondering why other posts were using np.where! So essentially what I was doing was passing the entire df into my new series and that's why it threw an error?

Comment: np.where is definitely very useful in if-else kind of a scenario when you need the output to be any data type other than boolean. Even for boolean it works but just that boolean masking is better. And yes, you were passing a df into the new series and hence the error. You can see what was happening by simply printing df.where(df['output'] > df['output'].median(), 1, 0)